# How to disable SNI on heroku?

Tags: ssl, heroku, sni

I have an heroku app with using Automated Certificate Management.
Some ssl customers say me that i should disable SNI support on the hosting.
How can i disable the SNI for this heroku app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From support:

Heroku ACM uses our SNI SSL endpoints. To have SSL that does not use our SNI endpoints, you'll need to use our SSL Endpoint add-on, https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint, and provision and manage your own SSL certificates.